# Fatal error : Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: SoapVar has no 'enc_type' property

Tags: php

I am doing Integration with Kashflow using PHP on one of my clients wordpress website and it was running great till PHP5.6 but the issue arrives when i had upgraded the website to PHP7.1, SO below is the error i am getting,
Fatal error
: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: SoapVar has no 'enc_type' property

Below is my Kashflow class code:

```
    public function insertInvoice(KashflowInvoice $invoice)

    {

        $lines = $this->prepareInvoiceLines($invoice->getLines());



        $parameters['Inv'] = array

        (

            "InvoiceDBID"       => 0,

            "InvoiceNumber"     => $invoice->getInvoiceNumber(),

            "InvoiceDate"       => $invoice->getInvoiceDate(),

            "DueDate"           => $invoice->getDueDate(),

            "Customer"          => "",

            "CustomerID"        => $invoice->getKashflowCustomerId(),

            "Paid"              => 1,

            "CustomerReference" => "",

            "EstimateCategory"  => "",

            "SuppressTotal"     => 1,

            "ProjectID"         => 0,

            "CurrencyCode"      => "GBP",

            "ExchangeRate"      => 1,

            "ReadableString"    => "",

            "Lines"             => $lines,

            "NetAmount"         => $invoice->getNet(),

            "VATAmount"         => $invoice->getTax(),

            "AmountPaid"        => 0,

            "CustomerName"      => "",

            "UseCustomDeliveryAddress" => 0

        );
            print_r($parameters);


        return $this->makeRequest("InsertInvoice",$parameters);

    }



    private function prepareInvoiceLines($invoice_lines)

    {

        if(NULL == $invoice_lines)
            return array();            

       $lines = NULL;            

        foreach($invoice_lines as $invoice_line)

        {

            $line = array(

                "LineID"      => 0,

                "Quantity"    => $invoice_line['qty'],

                "Description" => $invoice_line['description'],

                "Rate"        => $invoice_line['unit_net'],

                "ChargeType"  => $invoice_line['nominal_id'],

                "VatAmount"   => $invoice_line['qty'] * $invoice_line['unit_tax'],

                "VatRate"     => $invoice_line['tax_rate'],

                "Sort"        => 1,

                "ProductID"   => 0,

                "ProjID"      => $invoice_line['project_id']     
            );

          // Lines is an array of InvoiceLine as anyType.

           $lines[] = new SoapVar($line,0,"InvoiceLine","KashFlow");


        }



        return $lines;

    }
```

I debugged this code and it is creative invoice if i comment the "$lines[] = new SoapVar($line,0,"InvoiceLine","KashFlow");" SO i am not sure what to change on this line.

Your help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$lines[] = new SoapVar($line,0,"InvoiceLine","KashFlow");

Second argument should be a constant. Try using SOAP_ENC_OBJECT for example. More information can be found in php documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/soapvar.soapvar.php see example #1. List of constants that you can try is here: http://php.net/manual/en/soap.constants.php. Valid ones are staring with XSD_ for basic types and SOAP_ENC_*. 
If this fail please post wsdl file.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of 0 replace with `SOAP_ENC_OBJECT`, it's work for me php version 7.0

```
$lines[] = new SoapVar($line,SOAP_ENC_OBJECT,"InvoiceLine","KashFlow");
```